# como hacer un remote post desde mi sitio wordpress a una api en angular

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, angular

Necesito hacer un remote post desde mi sitio wordpress a una api en angular, para poder hacer un registro desde mi web.

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar la función remote post

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post

```
$respuesta = wp_remote_post( 'http://example.org/api' );
$respuesta_api = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $respuesta ), true );
```

source:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/274154/62765

Comment: pero la persona no tiene una api habilitada, pero si me gustaria traer el formulario.. y pues sé que su app esta en angular.... hay manera de hacerlo? solo con el formulario de la web.